# Javascript Array Push and then Splice it not working

Tags: javascript

So basically i want to remove the 3, with the 4.
So its just only "1":"2" left.

```
const array = [];

array.push({ "1": "2" })
array.push({ "3": "4" })


const index = array.indexOf(3);
if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(array)
```

Comment: You're pushing objects with key/value pairs so `indexOf` won't work in this case. [Here's the documentation for objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), and [the documentation for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: @RawleyFowler that won't work either as object equality assessed by reference not shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`In case of OBJECT values`**

If you are using `indexOf` with objects then you have to compare it with the exact same object. You need to have exact same reference to remove it from the array in which you have added prior.

> Objects are compared with references and primitives are compared with values. For more info, [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

```js
const array = [];
const obj = { '3': '4' };
array.push({ '1': '2' });
array.push(obj);

const index = array.indexOf(obj);
console.log(index);
```

**`In case of PRIMITIVE values`**

If the input is array of primitive values then you could have used `indexOf` because primitives are compared with value as:

```js
const array = ['1', '2', '3'];
console.log(array.indexOf('3'));
```

---

**1)** You can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to get the same result. Thanks to [`pilchard`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard) for this suggestion.

```js
const array = [];

array.push({ '1': '2' });
array.push({ '3': '4' });

const index = array.findIndex((o) => o.hasOwnProperty('3'));
if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(array);
```

**2)** You can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the index of the object who has `3` as a key

```js
const array = [];

array.push({ '1': '2' });
array.push({ '3': '4' });

const index = array.findIndex((o) => Object.keys(o).some((k) => k === '3'));
if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Or with the relevant Object method `array.findIndex((o) => Object.hasOwn(o, '3'))` (`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, '3')` for compatibility)

Comment: @pilchard [hasOwn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn#browser_compatibility) added recently, Its support is not so good

Comment: Which is why I noted the compatibility option using `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: Yeah, using `hasOwnProperty` is far more better, Thanks

Comment: @pilchard why to use `call` when we can directly use `o.hasOwnProperty('3')`

Comment: There are a few reasons, one being that `hasOwnProperty` is itself a property and can be overwritten (see: [Using hasOwnProperty as a property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#using_hasownproperty_as_a_property_name)), another is that `hasOwnProperty` will be inaccessible for objects that don't inherit from `Object.prototype` (see: [Objects created with Object.create(null)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#using_hasownproperty_as_a_property_name))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array.pop() method [Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) like this:

```
const array = [];

array.push({ 1: '2' });
array.push({ 2: '4' });
array.pop();

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Basically i dont want to delete the last, or the first. 
I want to delete a specific key

Answer (score 0):

Since you are pushing the whole object in the array after the two insertions your array would like something like this :
`[  {"1":"2"}, {"3":"4"} ]`

So when you perform the action indexOf, it does't return anything.

In order to get the desired result you can try using object and use delete to remove any property you don't want. Example

```js
const obj = {}

obj["1"] = "2";
obj["3"] = "4"

console.log("original obj : ", obj)

delete obj["3"];

console.log("filtered obj : ", obj)
```

Comment: Yeah but in my Code i need to push, so i cant just dont push.

Comment: Search with a whole Object would be relatively expensive operation than searching for a constant on a map or obj. you can still use array and create a map with constant lookup time.

Answer (score 0):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the objects. If [an object's key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) matches your search key it doesn't get returned in the filtered array.

```js
const arr = [];

arr.push({ 1: '2' })
arr.push({ 3: '4' })

function remove(arr, k) {
  return arr.filter(obj => {
    return Object.keys(obj)[0] !== k;
  });
}

console.log(remove(arr, '3'));
```